# rspec problem under rails 3.0 / ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I followed the tutorial book under http://railstutorial.org/ and found problem with `rspec`.

```
sudo rspec spec/ #caused sudo: rspec: command not found
```

If I used

```
sudo bundle exec rspec spec/ #Failure Error: Unable to find matching ....
```

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you shouldn't have to use sudo
2. try `bundle exec rspec spec/**/*.spec.rb` (or `bundle exec rspec spec/**/*_spec.rb` if your specs are called *_spec.rb)